# UITabBarController disappear in Three20 TTThumbsViewController

Tags: xcode, uitabbarcontroller, three20, ttthumbsviewcontroller

I'm having trouble put TTThumbsViewController and UITabBarController together. The tab bar will disappear when switched to TTThumbsViewController of Three20. I've read all questions in stack overflow and nothing really helped. And I even tried to set all

```
self.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO; 
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
```

in my thumbsviewcontroller and in Three20UI project. None of these methods work.

I'm building my app in Xcode4 with storyboard and adding this thumbs gallery is the last part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realise this is an oldish post but if you use:

```
self.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO; 
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
```

IT means that the push has already taken place therefore negating the command. Use this instead:

```
GalleryViewController *gallery = [[GalleryViewController alloc] init];
gallery.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO; 
gallery.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
```

Then push it. This works.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this problem by remove the three20 navigation bar in my code and simply use the uinavigationcontroller in storyboard. I don't know why, but problem solved. I hope this can help those like me using storyboard with three20.